# While using Spotify play button in mobile app, "the protocol is not supported"

Tags: android, jquery, mobile, cordova, spotify

I'm using jQuery mobile (building via PhoneGap) to build an app that incorporates the Spotify Play button.  It works loading the HTML in Chrome on my desktop - the song plays when I hit play.  When I build it and ship it to Android, it looks great, but clicking the play button throws this error:

> Application Error.  The protocol is not supported.  (spotify:track:36bDXIjlYQKTxESFmAPEK3)

The iframe code looks like this:

```
<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:album:6uX8TGL87F9aF15eCqmbPB" width="300" height="80" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I have tested on my Droid Incredible (old) and my Galaxy Tab 3.0 (new).  Same result.  Tried with album links and playlists, same result.  I have Spotify installed, and I'm a premium user.

I've tried using an iFrame with an embedded YouTube video instead, which works fine.

I've also tried moving the .html and .js over to my Incredible and opening the .html with the HTML Viewer that comes with the File Manager app (by Rhythm Software).  Clicking on play here gets me a "web page not available" (looks like a 404) for the "web page" spotify:track:36bDXI...etc.

Does the play button not work on mobile devices?  Do I need to package something with my .apk to make it work?  I'm new to mobile apps, feel free to talk to me like I'm stupid.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I'm [not the only one with this problem](http://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Web-Player/Protocol-isn-t-supported-error-using-Spotify-play-button-in/m-p/340774/thread-id/840).

Comment: Can you try opening a web page with that iframe from on a browser in your Android phones? Clicking on the play button should trigger your installed Spotify app. If this works, try to change the user agent used by PhoneGap and set it to a user agent corresponding to Chrome for Android or the old regular browser that came with older Android phones.

Comment: I just tried using web pages as the iframe source - one HTTP, one HTTPS - both were successful.  Your "user agent" tip is a bit over my head, but I'll figure it out and report back shortly.

Comment: JMPerez: I appreciate the suggestion, but even after researching I'm at a loss as to how changing the user agent will help this problem.  Can you clarify?  It seems that if the app can reach the web to load the Play button interface and graphics, the problem can't be based on browser - it's about the spotify protocol reaching the installed spotify app.

Comment: In short, depending on the browser, the behaviour of the Spotify Play Button differs when clicking the Play button.